# How can I append to a new div every 9 items?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm appending an array of options, but I want it to go to a different column after 9 items. Should I be doing this conditionally, or should I be appending them all, then using `.wrap` for 9?

This is the basics of what I have:

```
//array going through an each loop, item being a single item in said array

    _(all_topic).uniq().each(function (item) {
                $(".topicContainer").append('<li><input class="filterable-content__criteria" type="checkbox" name="topic" value="' + item + '" id="group3-'+item+'"><i class="hsg-icon hsg-icon-orange-checkmark"></i><label for="group3-'+ item +'">'+ item +'</label></li>')
            });
```

---

Should I be running a function immediately after that says

```
var topic_opts = $(".topicContainer li");
for(var i = 0; i < topic_opts.length; i+=9) {
  topic_opts.slice(i, i+9).wrapAll("<ul class="row+i"></ul>");
}
```

or is there a way I can do this in the append using a conditional?

Comment: Both options are valid, assuming your browser isn't automagically wrapping your orphaned li's with another ul

Comment: You may use the modulus: `if ( !(index % 9)) { .. }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this might help you. This will loop through the given array and add  at every 9th iteration (so 9, 18,...). Be aware, `index % 9 == 0` will also return true if `index == 0`.

```
$.each(object_array, function( index, value ) {
    if (index % 9 == 0) {
        container.append('<whatever>')
    }
})
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `nth-child()` for this.

Example below shows 9 `<li>` in a `<ul>`, it appends '3rd item' to every third item in the list.

```js
$('#list').children('li:nth-child(3n)').append('3rd item');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id='list'>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```